# Unable to Update Encrypted data with in grid view

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

i have encrypted password in the database, the problem is when i try to update the password in the gridview using sql datasource....."Scalar variable @password must be declared" messgae will dispaly.  here is the source code.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/menuMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PasswordReset.aspx.cs" Inherits="fcrHome" Title="Untitled Page" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" Runat="Server">
    <% 
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    %>
        <p>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        Password Reset Here</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 102px">
                        Oracle ID</td>
                    <td style="width: 143px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOracleid" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtoracleValidator" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtOracleid" ErrorMessage="Please Enter oracle Id"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 102px; height: 9px">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 143px; height: 9px">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 9px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="UserPrivilegeId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                        SortExpression="UserName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserPrivilegeName" HeaderText="UserPrivilegeName" 
                        SortExpression="UserPrivilegeName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserPassword" HeaderText="UserPassword" 
                        SortExpression="UserPassword" />
                </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <%
            String password1= "select UserPassword FROM tblUserPrivileges WHERE UserName = @UserName";
            Authentication authenticate = new Authentication();
            String password= authenticate.Encryption(password1);
            Response.Write(password); 

             %>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCF %>" 


            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblUserPrivileges] WHERE [UserPrivilegeId] = @UserPrivilegeId" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblUserPrivileges] ([UserName], [UserPrivilegeName], [UserPassword]) VALUES (@UserName, @UserPrivilegeName, @UserPassword)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [UserPrivilegeId], [UserName], [UserPrivilegeName], [UserPassword] FROM [tblUserPrivileges] WHERE ([UserName] = @UserName)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblUserPrivileges] SET [UserName] = @UserName, [UserPrivilegeName] = @UserPrivilegeName, [UserPassword] = @password ,[ModifiedDate] = getDate() WHERE [UserPrivilegeId] = @UserPrivilegeId">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtOracleid" Name="UserName" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>


            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPassword" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPassword" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </asp:Content>

How can i use variable in the sql data source ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPassword" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserPrivilegeId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
```

your parameter name is @UserPassword.

Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Hello Dear, Thank you very much for your fast support, your comment support to update the data as it is, not in encrypted form. please look on the above, i created object for authentication class and i call the encryption method and pass the password. now i need to update the data with encrypted data. how i handle it ?